# ts constructor signature example

Tags: typescript

Construct Signatures
JavaScript functions can also be invoked with the new operator. TypeScript refers to these as constructors because they usually create a new object. You can write a construct signature by adding the new keyword in front of a call signature:

```
type SomeConstructor = {
  new (s: string): SomeObject;
};
function fn(ctor: SomeConstructor) {
  return new ctor("hello");
}
```

How is the shape of the param?

```
const bb = (s: string) => {
  return {
    s
  }
}
fn(bb) // fail


fn(new bb('a')) // fail


fn((n: string) => ({})) // fail
```

Doc ref
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures

Comment: What is the question? `fn`  accepts only classes

Comment: Ohhhhh I see, that makes sense. TY